# How to show only a couple of the cfchartseries data on a cfchart when the page loads?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

I have created a `cfchart` with about 16 `cfchartseries` being pulled from a SQL database. Everything seems to be working, except I cannot figure out a way to only have 2 of the series show up when the page is loaded. Currently, all 16 show up and the chart is pretty muddled. My goal is to have the page load with only 2 of the series showing, and the user would then be able to toggle the rest on in the legend depending on what they want to see.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show at least some effort in trying to solve the problem yourself. Include the code that you have tried and explain how it is not working for you. Also include any error messages that you may be encountering.

Comment: I would abandon cfchart and use a proper client side charting library and just use coldfusion to prep the data for consumption to the client library the decent libraries pull in data via AJAX. 

That way your coldfusion code does not have to do any voodoo that most libraries provide out of the box. Checkout fusion charts as an option but there are some very nice looking free libraries available that I have also used.